# Cassandra get_range_slices

Tags: range, cassandra, fetch, slice

I am new to Cassandra and I am having some difficulties fetching data.
I looked into the function:

```
list<KeySlice> get_range_slices(column_parent, predicate, range, consistency_level)
```

But, I do not understand what the column_parent is supposed to be. 
Anybody any idea?=

Thanx,
Granit

Answer (score 1):

column_parent is basicly used for indicator of ColumnFamily(but in rare cases it can indicate a supercolumn). In java you would put : `new ColumnParent("Posts")` there. but there should be one more parameter for namespace in get_range_slices query, I guess you are not using thrift but a client api. then you should check your client's documentation.

**Edit:**

the definition of ColumnParent in cassandra api :

> The ColumnParent is the path to the
>   parent of a particular set of Columns.
>   It is used when selecting groups of
>   columns from the same ColumnFamily. In
>   directory structure terms, imagine
>   ColumnParent as ColumnPath + '/../'.

Answer (score 0):

Frail is correct, but the real answer is "don't use raw Thrift, use one of the clients from http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ClientOptions instead."